# In Red, how do I search through a block for a string matching a pattern?

Tags: red

Given:

```
player-wins: [
    "rock breaks scissors"
    "paper covers rock"
    "scissors cut paper"
    ]
```

I want a function which accepts two strings, each representing any of rock, paper or scissors and then returns the element that matches, ignoring the verb.

Example:

`does-player-win "paper" "rock"` should return "paper covers rock" by searching the block.

**UPDATE** I tried to change the structure to make it easy for `find` or `select` but apparently my structure is illegal:

```
player-wins: [
    ["rock" "scissors"] "breaks"
    ["paper" "rock"] "covers"
    ["scissors" "paper"] "cut"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I almost forgot the most simple solution

```
player-wins: [
    "rock"  "breaks" "scissors"
    "paper" "covers"" rock" 
    "scissors" "cuts"  "paper"
]

game: func [player1 player2]  [
    foreach [subject predicate object] player-wins [
        all [
            player1 = subject
            player2 = object
            return reduce [player1 predicate player2]
        ]
    ]
]

>> print game "rock" "scissors"
rock breaks scissors
>> print game "scissors" "paper"
scissors cut paper
```

But also your second structure fits

```
player-wins: [
    ["rock" "scissors"] "breaks"
    ["paper" "rock"] "covers"
    ["scissors" "paper"] "cut"
]

win: function [player1 player2] [
    game: reduce [player1 player2]
    winning: player-wins/(game)
    print [player1 winning player2]
]


>> win "paper" "rock" 
paper covers rock
```

or short

```
win: func [player1 player2] [
    print [player1 select/only player-wins reduce [player1 player2] player2]
]
```

And an optimized version independent of the order covering all variations could be like this

```
player-wins: [
    "rock" "breaks" 
    "scissors" "cuts" 
    "paper" "covers" 
    "rock" "is covered by" 
    "paper" "is cut by" 
    "scissors" "will be broken by" "rock" 
]

game: func [player1 player2] [
    parse player-wins [
        collect [some [keep [player1 skip player2] | 2 skip]    ]   
    ]
 ]

 >> print game "scissors" "rock"
 scissors will be broken by rock
 >> print game "rock" "scissors"
 rock breaks scissors
```

Comment: is the `reduce` necessary on `game: reduce [player1 player2]` - it seems you could just do `game: [player1 player2]`.

Comment: Yes it's needed. It replaces the words player1 and player2 with their value. [player1 player2] are not in your block. A block shields against direct evaluation.